# Lumen (Laravel): "Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost'" when running "php artisan migrate:install"

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

Running through a Lumen tutorial that was written a year ago and several versions prior to the latest version of Lumen.

I've created an .env file which contains MySQL credentials for my project however when I attempt to run this:

```
php artisan migrate:install
```

I'm met with the following error:

```
Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost'
```

So it seems apparent after Googling that it's not picking up my custom .env (i.e. custom.env) file. In the tutorial, it advises to uncomment this:

```
Dotenv::load(__DIR__.'/../');
```

From bootstrap/app.php however that line doesn't exist. There is however a *try* statement that looks like this:

```
  try {
      (new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__.'/../'))->load();
  } catch (Dotenv\Exception\InvalidPathException $e) {
      //
  }
```

but it's uncommented and active. My custom .env is in the project root directory - same location as .env.example - and named ***custom.env***.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

## RTM

It states in Lumen documentation (https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.2/configuration#environment-configuration):

"You should rename the .env.example file to .env when creating your application."

I named my custom .env file ***custom.env***. It only needed to be ***.env***.

Ran *php artisan migrate:install* and the migration table was created successfully.